# Copyfile of current project that works in shared mode gives "Permission denied" in exclusive mode

Tags: ms-access, vba

The following is a greatly stripped-down version of some Access 2013 code which simply makes a copy of the current project under a new name.

It works only if the file is open in shared mode.  If open in exclusive mode, this generates a "Permission denied" error.

```
Private Sub TestCopy()

    Dim sSourceFile, sSourcePath, sTargetFile, sTargetPath As String
    Dim AccessObj As Object

    sSourceFile = CurrentProject.Name
    sSourcePath = CurrentProject.Path
    sTargetFile = "TestCopy.accdb"
    sTargetPath = CurrentProject.Path

    Set AccessObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    AccessObj.CopyFile sSourcePath & "\" & sSourceFile, sTargetPath & "\" & sTargetFile, True
    Set AccessObj = Nothing

End Sub
```

I'm surprised my research doesn't explain this.  Is there another file copying method I can use within a database open in exclusive mode?  Or do I need a method that runs outside the database?

Comment: try FileCopy source, destination

Comment: The documentation says that doesn't work with a file open at all, shared or exclusive, but will give it a try.

Comment: Documentation appears to be right; FileCopy doesn't work with any open file.

Comment: try the methods with windows api calls described here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/172711 down the page. there is 2 methods, you can try both, one is using windows api and the other one uses MS-DOS

Comment: Thanks, Sol.  I'd seen that article, and thought its CopyFile method was the same as mine; these are different beasts?  I was going to hold off a bit for another answer before I tried the DOS method, as I haven't used the shell function yet, but guess I'll try that now.

Comment: the CopyFile method that is being described in that article is a windows api call, Declare Function apiCopyFile Lib "kernel32" Alias "CopyFileA" _
      (ByVal lpExistingFileName As String, _
      ByVal lpNewFileName As String, _
      ByVal bFailIfExists As Long) As Long i think it uses a different approach then what your code does, i am not 100% sure on that, but its worth a try.

Comment: The DOS method behaves exactly like CopyFile: works for a shared-mode .accdb file but not one opened in exclusive mode.  I haven't understood what API calls are about, so I guess it's time.

Comment: With that link's API call, keep getting "invalid outside procedure" error, but considering that's an archived 1995 article, probably unsurprising.

Comment: whats your pc spec? 64bit?

Comment: i have tested it on a Windows10 machine using access2007 with a Northwind sample database open and it worked, here is my code i used.

Comment: Option Explicit

      Declare Function apiCopyFile Lib "kernel32" Alias "CopyFileA" _
      (ByVal lpExistingFileName As String, _
      ByVal lpNewFileName As String, _
      ByVal bFailIfExists As Long) As Long

Comment: and then          Sub CopyFile(SourceFile As String, DestFile As String)

      '---------------------------------------------------------------
        Dim Result As Long
         If Dir(SourceFile) = "" Then
            MsgBox Chr(34) & SourceFile & Chr(34) & _
               " is not valid file name."
         Else
            Result = apiCopyFile(SourceFile, DestFile, False)
         End If
      End Sub

Comment: Public Sub test()

CopyFile "C:\Users\*****\Documents\Northwind.accdb", "C:\Test\Northwind.accdb"
MsgBox "done"

End Sub

Comment: Yes, 64 bit, cool, I'll try that out.  But you know, I've been reading how it's not a great idea to copy an open file.  I've done it a bunch with no problems, but it's probably best I switch gears and write a batch file that copies the file while closed, then opens the database in exclusive mode.  It's still curious to me that this CopyFile behavior is not documented anywhere that I can find; seems a major thing many would like to know who are writing backup utilities.

Comment: any update on what helped?

Comment: What helped?  Giving up!  I admit I didn't keep working on that API call.  Maybe it's a sour grapes thing, but I switched to an external batch file copying a closed file.  Although this may end up being problematic, as my company is about to take away administrator rights from everyone on their own PC, and can't tell me if that will affect batch files.  For that reason I'd still like to have the answer to this in my back pocket in case I need it.  If that comes I'll keep debugging the API call.  Thanks so much for brainstorming with me, Sol, it really helps.