# Copy Access Database using VBA code from within

Tags: vba, ms-access, copy

Is there a way to copy an Access database from within itself through VBA code?
I've tried using fso.CopyFile and FileCopy but they lead to permission errors since the file is already open.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39127550/copyfile-of-current-project-that-works-in-shared-mode-gives-permission-denied

Comment: Thanks, I use a library function from shell32.dll and it was able to copy the opened file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that you can use a shell32.dll function to copy the open file. I even added the progress bar functionality. Here is the code

```
Declare Function SHFileOperation Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "SHFileOperationA" (lpFileOp As SHFILEOPSTRUCT) As Long

Public Const FO_COPY = &H2
Public Const FOF_SIMPLEPROGRESS = &H100

Public Type SHFILEOPSTRUCT
    hWnd As Long
    wFunc As Long
    pFrom As String
    pTo As String
    fFlags As Integer
    fAnyOperationsAborted As Long
    hNameMappings As Long
    lpszProgressTitle As Long
End Type

Public Sub VBCopyFile(ByRef strSource As String, ByRef strTarget As String)
     Dim op As SHFILEOPSTRUCT

     With op
       .wFunc = FO_COPY
       .pTo = strTarget
       .pFrom = strSource
       .fFlags = FOF_SIMPLEPROGRESS
    End With

    '~~> Perform operation
    SHFileOperation op
End Sub
```

I just needed to call the VBCopyFile Sub with the appropriate parameters and it worked.